# Suppress specific ligature in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, ligatures

Is there a way to selectively disable a specific ligature in XeLaTex? I cannot see how. The selnolig package seems to do what I need but I don't even know how to use Lualatex with my Texshop setup on Mac.

Specifics:
I am using XeLaTex, new to it and trying to figure my way around and set up some standard templates for my own use, e.g. academic papers. I am mostly using Linux Libertine O. I have the same issue with Adobe Caslon Pro.

Why:
The "Th" ligature bothers me, particularly in titles. I never see it used in print. See, for example, the New Yorker magazine which uses Caslon, most ligatures are set but never Th. I never see it in books either. (I know this is picky).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does `T\/h` not work?

Comment: I find the “Th” ligature too pompous and usually awful.

Comment: Christian, is there a way to use T\/h as a macro instead of for each individual case?

Comment: @jhg540: Well, there might be, but isn't `search and replace Th by T\/h` the better way? ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately “Th” is in the base ligatures, at least in Linux Libertine, which in my opinion is a wrong decision.

Comment: To run LuaLaTeX from TeXshop, select "LuaLaTeX" from the drop-down menu located next to the "Typeset" button. Then, click on "Typeset" to compile your document with LuaLaTeX (instead of, say, XeLaTeX).

Comment: This is not just about the "look", but also about functionality: Words with ligatures are often not findable in (otherwise) searchable PDFs.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you can figure out how to use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX from within TeXshop (not a difficult switch to make, really), you could indeed use the `selnolig` package to suppress the `Th` ligature *globally* throughout your document. Consider the following example (compiled under TeXshop, having selected "LuaLaTeX" from the drop-down menu):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\usepackage{selnolig}
\nolig{Th}{T|h} % suppress "Th" ligature globally
\begin{document}
The There They Then (Th-ligature disabled)

vs.
\selnoligoff %% suspend operation of selnolig's rules

The There They Then (Th-ligature re-enabled)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there is no official way to disable a specific ligature.  There are two workarounds: defining a new mapping, as egreg suggested, or using the `XeTeXinterchartokenstate` mechanism.

The latter is the one I prefer.  I start by defining two character classes: `FirstClass` for `T` and `SecondClass` for `h`:

```
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\FirstClass
\XeTeXcharclass`T\FirstClass
\newXeTeXintercharclass\SecondClass
\XeTeXcharclass`h\SecondClass
```

I then instruct XeTeX to insert zero-size glue between `T` and `h`:

```
\XeTeXinterchartoks\FirstClass\SecondClass={\penalty\@M\hskip\z@}
```

Note that I'm using `\hskip`, which inserts glue, rather than `\kern`, which inserts a kern, as the latter has the side-effect of disabling hyphenation.  However glue allows line breaks, which I disable by inserting a penalty.

No kerning will be applied between the `T` and the `h`, so you might need to tweak the width of the glue.

Comment: Nice trick; however just the penalty and a single class suffice.

Comment: @egreg probably true about just needing the penalty, but in practice you're going to need to do some manual kerning.  How do you manage with just a single class?

Comment: ``\newXeTeXintercharclass\noTh\XeTeXcharclass`T\noTh\XeTeXcharclass`h\noTh``
`\XeTeXinterchartoks\noTh\noTh={\penalty10000 }`

Comment: That's going to have the side effect of disabling any kerning between h and T.  Probably not an issue, though.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if a kerning between `h` and `T` was defined in the first place. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you, and also @egreg, for the excellent answers. I have some time later today and I will explore both.

Answer (score 5):

This is the least trickier solution, but it worked for me many times. Just before compiling do a search and replace of all `Th` by `\Th` (with a trailing space), with

```
\newcommand*\Th{T\kern0pt h}
```

This might seem less fun, but I think it's enough (it won't really pollute your source with tons of macros, just `\Th` once in a while).

Comment: I do not discuss if `\penalty\@M\hskip\z@` is better (because of hyphenation), I just wanted to point out how easy is to use a macro (for this specific case).

Comment: +1 for sheer ingenuity! Do note that because TeX doesn't hyphenate words that contain an explicit kern, words such as `\Th inspace` and `\Th ickness` may no longer be hyphenated with this approach.

Comment: If you just want to modify a single bit of text, this solution is great. I have a title with `Listing of Figures` in which I wanted to suppress the flourish of an `st` ligature. Using kern-space solution above (e.g., `Lis\kern-1pt ting of figures`) without the `\newcommand` allowed me to simply adjust one title without needing to modify the whole document.

Answer (score 4):

In Linux Libertine, the Th ligature is among the basic ones, so either you disable all of them or you get it.

A way out is to load a special mapping. Copy the `tex-text.map` file you find in your TeX distribution and rename it `tex-text-noth.map`, adding a bottom line so that it becomes

```
; TECkit mapping for TeX input conventions <-> Unicode characters

LHSName "TeX-text-noth"
RHSName "UNICODE"

pass(Unicode)

; ligatures from Knuth's original CMR fonts
U+002D U+002D           <>  U+2013  ; -- -> en dash
U+002D U+002D U+002D    <>  U+2014  ; --- -> em dash

U+0027          <>  U+2019  ; ' -> right single quote
U+0027 U+0027   <>  U+201D  ; '' -> right double quote
U+0022           >  U+201D  ; " -> right double quote

U+0060          <>  U+2018  ; ` -> left single quote
U+0060 U+0060   <>  U+201C  ; `` -> left double quote

U+0021 U+0060   <>  U+00A1  ; !` -> inverted exclam
U+003F U+0060   <>  U+00BF  ; ?` -> inverted question

; additions supported in T1 encoding
U+002C U+002C   <>  U+201E  ; ,, -> DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
U+003C U+003C   <>  U+00AB  ; << -> LEFT POINTING GUILLEMET
U+003E U+003E   <>  U+00BB  ; >> -> RIGHT POINTING GUILLEMET

; disable Th
U+0054 U+0068   <>      U+0054 U+200C U+0068
```

Then run

```
teckit_compile tex-text-noth.map
```

and try the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text-noth]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
The
\end{document}
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

You can move the files `tex-text-noth.map` and `tex-text-noth.tex` in your personal TeX tree (or have them in the same folder as your main file); on a Unix system you should do

```
mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/noth
cp tex-text-noth.* $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping/noth/
```

No idea if you're using MiKTeX, sorry.