# Emdash in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, ligatures

Can someone explain the differences in how an *emdash* is rendered by LuaLaTex from this code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum---dolor---sit amet.
Lorem ipsum—dolor—sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

Why is the first dash in the first line shorter? I have read through what seem to be related questions:

- [Change em-dash character in an OpenType font with xetex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/279139)
- [Suppress specific ligature in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211202)
- [How to enable ligatures for emdash/endash in LuaTeX ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20580)

but I'm not sure whether this is quite the same question, and these discussions are fairly old.

Emdashes in the [font documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/tex-gyre/doc/qpl-info.pdf) don't seem to have this issue, but I can't find the .tex file that generated the documentation to see what commands are being used.

Simply put, my question is what is causing these to be rendered differently, and can I change it to make it consistent?

Comment: Add `\automatichyphenmode=1` to your preamble